# How to set threshold brightness in Xfce?

Tags: 16.04, shortcut-keys, laptop, xfce, brightness

I would like to know how to set **threshold** brightness that can be adjusted via the brightness keys (F11, F12) in my case.

When I press F11, the brightness is going too minimum that it ends up in black screen (exactly 0 brightness).

For example, in Windows 8.1, decreasing the brightness via F11, even if the indicator shows 0, it isn't actually 0 but some value which is visible.

P.S:

> **xbacklight** sets the brightness to low, but it needs to start at
>   the system startup which I've done. It is OK. But, what I want is not
>   a brightness at startup, but adjusting of brightness with the keys, so
>   that the minimum brightness which I set shouldn't go to exactly 0 even
>   if the slider shows 0.

See, when the brightness is adjusted with the Power Manager indicator in Xfce, even if the Slider shows 0, the brightness is set to a value that is not exactly 0 but something reasonable.
It's value is **0.533618** (which I got using xbacklight). This value I would like to have as threshold.

So, how to set this value as threshold value for brightness.

P.S: I don't want to install any additional software for this.

Comment: I have a script I wrote for my wife's laptop that does just what you're looking for. I don't have it with me right now. I'll plan to post in the next few days.

Answer (score 0):

The usage for the following script is `script-name -d` to decrease brightness and `script-name -u` to increase brightness. You can set a keyboard shortcut for F11 and F12 respectively. I believe the keyboard shortcut will override your current use for those two keys. Remember to make it executable by running the command `chmod +x script-name`. It is possible that the file that controls your brightness is not `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`. It could be something very similar though such as in the directory `acpi_video1` instead. It might take a little digging around.

```
#!/bin/bash

file="/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness"

num=$(cat "$file")

case $1 in
    -u)
        ((num++)) ;;
    -d)
        ((num--)) ;;
    *)
        echo "This is not an option." ;;
esac

if [ "$num" = 10 ]; then
    notify-send "You are at max brightness."
    exit 1
fi

if [ "$num" = -1 ]; then
    notify-send "You are at minimum brightness."
    exit 1
fi

echo "$num" > "$file"
```

You will need to add the following to `/etc/rc.local` before `exit 0`.

```
chown username:username /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

Replace `username` with the output of the command `echo $USER`. You need to run the above command or reboot with this line in `/etc/rc.local` before the above script will work. Adding the line to `/etc/rc.local` is necessary because eventually on reboot, `brightness` will change to root ownership again. Then the above script won't be able to write to it. Please let me know if any issues come up.

Comment: Error: brightness.sh: 11: brightness.sh: num--: not found

Comment: That is OK. But how to bind it to brightness indicator (with progressbar) like we get usually a slider showing the brightness?

Comment: @JavaTechnical Did it work for you? Is the only issue that it is not showing the notification slider?

Comment: Yes. It must show in the brightness slider (not just show some notification as in the above code).